# Can any one say which Schematic Software is used for this Circuit diagram

Tags: schematics

[image: Software Used to Draw]

Can any one say which Schematic Software is used for this circuit diagram. I know Eagle and Pspice

Comment: It does look hand done in a graphics package, maybe using an electronics clip-art library. I would just re-draw it. Or ask the author of the blog where you saw it.

Comment: Agree. Note the difference in size of the connection dots at the top (C1) vs the left side (C4).  Also not schematic editor would show GND (pin 20 of U1) like that.

Answer (score 4):

That was likely hand drawn in a graphics program. Note the irregularity of the P1 pin labels.

Comment: Who ever DownVoted, why?  That is an astute if unverifiable observation.  Compensatory Up Vote granted.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not Eagle, Orcad, or Altium.  Each of those has their own distinctive look and characteristics, which your example differs from in a number of ways.